# query to exchange the names and select from a column name using mysql

Tags: mysql

For suppose we have a data similar to

```
firstname1,lastname1
firstname2,lastname2
firstname3,lastname3
firstname4,lastname4
```

I want a select statement to be returned where the output will look like

```
name
lastname1,firstname1
lastname2,firstname2
lastname3,firstname3
lastname4,firstname4
```

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract the two names, and `CONCAT()` to put them back together in the opposite order.

Comment: Why don't you just put them into separate columns in the first place, instead of a single comma-separated string?

Comment: I want it to be done without creating new column

Comment: I know you do. It just seems like a poor design because then you have to do silly things like this.

Comment: Consider a table with separate columns for firstname and lastname and a calculated column *name* that concatenates as required.

Comment: wrote a subquery to split the value and used concat_ws for fetching the output . Thanks